# golang - Exit http handler from anywhere

Tags: go, go-http

I'm using the net/http package and wondering how I can exit the handler from anywhere in the code. Say I have this code:

```
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    err := checkSomeThing(w, r)

    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("End of Handler.")
    return
}

func checkSomeThing(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) error{
    http.Error(w, "Bad Request!", http.StatusBadRequest) 
    
    return errors.New("bad request")
}
```

Ideally I'd like to exit the handler from within the checkSomeThing function without having to return and then return again up a level, which will get worse as the application grows. This is purely for code readability.

Comment: Explicit return statements are far more readable than any kind of panic shenanigans, the only alternative.

Comment: This looks a lot like this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39320025/how-to-stop-http-listenandserve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idiomatic approach is to check error returns up the call chain.

To exit the the handler from anywhere, use panic and recover following the [pattern in the encoding/json package](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/c5da4fb7ac5cb7434b41fc9a1df3bee66c7f1a4d/src/encoding/json/encode.go#L322-L330).

Define a unique type for panic:

```
type httpError struct {
    status  int
    message string
}
```

Write a function to be used in a defer statement.  The function checks for the type and handles the error as appropriate. Otherwise, the function continues the panic.

```
func handleExit(w http.ResponseWriter) {
    if r := recover(); r != nil {
        if he, ok := r.(httpError); ok {
            http.Error(w, he.message, he.status)
        } else {
            panic(r)
        }
    }
}
```

Write a helper function for the call to panic:

```
func exit(status int, message string) {
    panic(httpError{status: status, message: message})
}
```

Use the functions like this:

```
func example() {
   exit(http.StatusBadRequest, "Bad!")
}

func someHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
   defer handleExit(w)
   example()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**My answer:**
First, the common pattern established in Golang is to have errors "bubble up" from callee back to caller as a return value. It has a lot of advantages with regards to readability and re-use. The side effect is that there's a lot of `if err != nil {return}` checks.

**My suggestion if you really want to break from the norm**

I'm going to pitch an idea, that I don't think is common or standard with respect to golang coding styles and patterns.  But I didn't see anything online suggesting this was catastrophic.  Let's see what I get in the comments to say this is awful.

You could use [runtime.Goexit()](https://pkg.go.dev/runtime#Goexit) to achieve what you want. The handler just waits on another goroutine to do the work. If the inner code running in the go-routine wants to abort processing, it can call Goexit(). It has the advantage that all `defer` statements will still execute.

This just seems like a weak version of exception handling that Golang currently doesn't support. But I'm throwing it out there.

```
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    var cleanExit bool = false
    var ch = make(chan bool)

    // the actual handler implementation in a goroutine
    go func() {
        defer close(ch)
        handlerImpl(w, r)
        cleanExit = true // if handlerImpl invokes goExit, this line doesn't execute
    }()

    // wait for goroutine to exit
    <-ch

    if cleanExit {
        fmt.Println("Handler exited normally")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Hanlder was aborted")
    }
}

func handlerImpl(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    checkSomeThing(w, r)
}

func checkSomeThing(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.Error(w, "Bad Request!", http.StatusBadRequest)
    runtime.Goexit()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `checkSomeThing()` is specific to that route, you should probably keep going with the code sample you pasted.

If `checkSomeThing()` is a function common to all your routes (or to a subset of routes), you can choose a way to run a middleware before calling the handler for specific routes.

See for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53678633/understanding-the-http-handlerfunc-wrapper-technique-in-go) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71214499/86072), or here is a way to do it using only code from the standard http package :

```golang
func checkSomething(...) error {
    ...
}

func WrapWithCheck(handler http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        err := checkSomething(w, req)
        if err != nil {
            return
        }

        handler.ServeHTTP(w, req)
    })
}

func setupRouter() http.Handler {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("/foo/", handleFoo)
    mux.HandleFunc("/bar/", handleBar)
    mux.HandleFunc("/baz/", handleBaz)

    // add your common call to 'checkSomething' here :
    handler := WrapWithCheck(mux)
    return handler
}
```

[playground](https://go.dev/play/p/wJ2F0v_yB5p)

*note* : I tried using `httptest` in the playground above, and for some reason it deadlocks in the playground. It works fine if you copy/paste this code in a `sample.go` file and use `go run sample.go`